# How do AUC/Sensitivity/Specificity values differ in a k fold cross validation vs that in a development set?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret

For reproducibility, I have the following code, using the TitanicSurvival data set (10 fold cross validation repeated 3 times) in R.

Also, I am new to the forums and quite new to R, so I apologize in advance if I've broken any forum guidelines. I'll correct any mistakes if noted.

```
library(caret)
library(pROC)
df <- TitanicSurvival
df2 <- na.omit(df)

#Multiple regression model on df2:

titanic <- glm(survived~ sex + age, family=binomial, data = df2)

roc(df2$survived, titanic$fitted.values) # AUC = 0.7735
pred <- ifelse(predict(titanic, df2, type="response")>0.5, 1, 0)
actual <- titanic$y
conf_mat <- table(pred, actual)
sensitivity(conf_mat) # 0.8449111
specificity(conf_mat) # 0.6838407

#Now, using 10-fold cross validation repeated 3 times, on the same df2 data set:

ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", repeats = 3, number = 10, classProbs = TRUE, 
                          summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, savePredictions = T)

model <- train(survived ~ sex + age,
                  data = df2, trControl=ctrl, method="glm", preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                  metric="ROC")

# Model ROC(AUC): 0.7738766, Sens: 0.8449321, Spec: 0.6840347
```

Now, my questions are:

1. How are the AUC/Sens/Spec values in the cross validation model calculated? I'm trying to understand this output considering that the 10-fold CV creates multiple training and testing sets.
2. How do the AUC/Sens/Spec values in the cross validation model differ from that shown in the "titanic" model?
3. In the medical literature, some studies perform multiple regression with k-fold cross validation, without an external validation set. In this particular study, when they write "model accurately distinguished presence of HCC with c-statistics of 0.84 (95%CI 0.81-0.86) and 0.83 (95%CI 0.80-0.85) in derivation and validation cohorts (Figure 1), respectively", what does this mean? Since k-fold CV creates multiple training sets and testing sets, how does one come up with these respective values? [source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26125462)

Sorry for the long questions, but I've been doing a lot of searching and still can't get a clear understanding.

Thanks!

Comment: There are no answers yet, and there is more than one question asked, which doesn't make it a good question for migration. Please read https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask before cross-posting there.

Comment: 1) In most cases the metrics for CV are calculated by averaging the values obtained for each test set performed (there are 30 train/test splits when you perform 3 times repeated 10 fold CV). But there are other ways which are more appropriate when the test sets are small. 2) The CV metrics are based on test set performance - the model has not seen this data, and are therefore more unbiased then the train set values.

Comment: 3) As mentioned above for 1, metrics calculated based on CV are the average, but you can also mention the variance and get a 95%CI, but this CI will depend a lot on the number of folds and repetitions . Instead of this I would rather plot a boxplot which will show the distribution of the metric during CV.

Comment: To expand on "But there are other ways": In some packages like mlr one can define how the CV metric [aggregation is performed](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/aggregations.html). For some methods an explanation is given on the linked page. In most pipelines `test.mean` is the one used, but in some cases `testgroup.mean` and `test.join` should be considered especially when the distribution of the metric across re-samples is skewed, or the variance of the metric is high.